# Bash command : replace text starting

Tags: bash

Starting: Intent { cmp=com.tencent.ig/com.epicgames.ue4.SplashActivity
How to change the starting text in bash?
I need some solution for this.
Thanks!
I use termux

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'cmp=com.tencent.ig/com.epicgames.ue4.SplashActivity' | sed 's/com.tencent.ig/mynewtext/'
```

If you want to process the content of your file :

```
sed 's/com.tencent.ig/mynewtext/' yourfile.txt
```

To replace the first 4 characters :

```
sed 's/^..../mynewtext/' yourfile.txt
```

To replace everything at the beginning preceding the characher "=" (included) :

```
sed 's/^.*=//'  yourfile.txt
```